# Change Array Keys after Post

Tags: php

I'm working on an order form for a caterer.

### form.html

Contains many input fields, each for a food item.  At this stage, they are named generally.  For example:

```
<td><input name="Fish1" class="val2"/></td>
<td><input name="Fish2" class="val2"/></td>
<td><input name="Fish3" class="val2"/></td>
<td><input name="BakedSalmon1" class="val2"/></td>
<td><input name="BakedSalmon2" class="val2"/></td>
<td><input name="BakedSalmon3" class="val2"/></td>
<td><input name="RawSalmon1" class="val2"/></td>
<td><input name="RawSalmon2" class="val2"/></td>
<td><input name="RawSalmon3" class="val2"/></td>
```

It also has these (and more) hidden fields at the beginning of the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="OrderID" value="<? echo time(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="OrderDate" value="<? echo $today; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="">
```

After pressing "review your order", form gets POST'ed to `review.php`

### review.php

At this stage, I would like to have the specific names of the items.  So, for example:

```
/* Create Clean Array */
$CleanPost = $_POST;
foreach($CleanPost as $key => $link) 
{ 
    if($link === '') 
    { 
        unset($CleanPost[$key]); 
    } 
} 

/* Rename Array Keys */
foreach ($CleanPost as $keys => $var) {
if (empty($vars)) continue; #skip if vars is empty
if ($keys == "Fish1") { $keys = "Sweet n’ Sour Salmon";}
if ($keys == "Fish2") { $keys = "Baked Fish";}
if ($keys == "Fish3") { $keys = "Fish in Vegetables and Tomato Sauce";}
if ($keys == "BakedSalmon1") { $keys = "Teriyaki Salmon - Baked";}
if ($keys == "BakedSalmon2") { $keys = "Glazed Salmon -  Baked";}
if ($keys == "BakedSalmon3") { $keys = "Seasoned Salmon - Baked";}
if ($keys == "RawSalmon1") { $keys = "Teriyaki Salmon - Raw";}
if ($keys == "RawSalmon2") { $keys = "Glazed Salmon -  Raw";}
if ($keys == "RawSalmon3") { $keys = "Seasoned Salmon - Raw";}
```

One reason I am trying to do this, is because I am trying to show the customer a preview of their order, and obviously the general Fish1 Fish2 isn't going to be helpful.  Additionally, a "confirmation email / invoice" will be sent to both customer and caterer, which will need to show the specific item names.

Here's the code I'm using to show order review:

```
<p>Please review your order:</p>
<form action="submit.php" method="post" id="orderform" name="orderform">
    <table>
        <?
        foreach ($CleanPost as $index => $val) {
            echo("<tr><td>$index</td><td>$val</td></tr>");
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

I've tried `array_combine`, was unsuccessful in getting it to work.  Honestly, I've tried many things over the last 5 hours, and haven't been successful.  I know that sounds cliche, but I'm serious :)

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have an array of all the items full names, in case that helps.

**EDIT**:
I removed the hidden input fields from `form.html`.  I then tried:

```
$PostVals = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $var) {
    $PostVals[] = $var;
}
$NewKeysVals = array();
$NewKeysVals = array_combine($FullNames, $PostVals);

--
foreach ($NewKeysVals as $index => $val) {
echo("<tr><td>$index</td><td>$val</td></tr>");
```

and it worked!  Very, very strange.

It's 4AM here, I think I've spent too long looking at this that I'm wasting everyone else's time.  Will give it a fresh look tomorrow, and post back if necessary.  Thank you everyone (esp. @Spectarion) for answering so quickly and your willingness to help!

Comment: What's the problem? Error?

Comment: With array_combine, or replacing the $keys?

Comment: In general. Why are you having problems?

Comment: If you really want to keep this as an array based thing why not instead of changing the key, make it a 2d array so you can add as much as you want to each key? You could add price name sauce whatever to go with each key that you already have.

Comment: You have a typo. `if (empty($vars)) continue; #skip if vars is empty` should be `if (empty($var)) continue; #skip if vars is empty`. Or just use `if(isset($var)) { ... }`.

Comment: Okay, I just tried it again, and this time it worked.  I removed the hidden forms from the html page.  Going to edit OP.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @Spectarion, thank you very much for your help.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as correct for future readers. It helps me and the others :).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an array of keys and their real names.

```
// You posted only portion of items. Please, enter all of them.
$keyNames = [
    "Fish1" => "Sweet n’ Sour Salmon",
    "Fish2" => "Baked Fish",
    "Fish3" => "Fish in Vegetables and Tomato Sauce",
    "BakedSalmon1" => "Teriyaki Salmon - Baked",
    "BakedSalmon2" => "Glazed Salmon -  Baked",
    "BakedSalmon3" => "Seasoned Salmon - Baked",
    "RawSalmon1" => "Teriyaki Salmon - Raw",
    "RawSalmon2" => "Glazed Salmon -  Raw",
    "RawSalmon3" => "Seasoned Salmon - Raw"
    // etc ...
];

foreach ($CleanPost as $keys => $var)
{
    // If key name exists, assign it to the current $keys variable.
    if(isset($var) && isset($keyNames[$keys])) {
        $keys = $keyNames[$keys];
    }
}
```